# Return occurrence of pixels in a histogram OpenCV python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I need to return number of pixels starting by a bin value in a Histogram

```
def finalHisto(img):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    hist,bins = numpy.histogram(gray.flatten(),256,[0,256])
    cdf = hist.cumsum()
    cdf_normalized = cdf *hist.max()/ cdf.max()


    plt.figure()
    plt.title("Grayscale/CDF Histogram")
    plt.xlabel("Bins")
    plt.ylabel("# of Pixels")
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
    plt.plot(hist, color = 'b')
    #posso riempire l'histogramma
    #plt.hist(gray.flatten(),256,[0,256], color = 'g')
    plt.plot(cdf_normalized, color = 'r')
    plt.legend(('histogram','CDF'), loc = 'lower right')


    plt.show()
```

I need to return the numbers of pixel in each bin [0,255] of all histogram

The code return this: [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XKKQ.png)

For example I need to know the pixel number of the 55th bin

Comment: I don't understand your question. Isn't the variable `hist` what you are looking for?

Comment: Edited post, tell me if need more details, i can't understand how to iterate the x-axis of the histogram and return the pixel number values

Comment: `print(hist[54])` ?

Comment: yes, it works. :-)